# error while deploying my zip folder api proxy

Tags: azure, azure-devops, proxy, apigee

I am trying to deploy my proxy as a zip folder, but got this error:

> {
> "code" : "messaging.config.beans.InvalidBundle",
> "message" : "Bundle is invalid. Parse error",
> "contexts" : [ ]

I am trying to deploy API proxy using Azure devops pipeline

Comment: It would be next to impossible to help without any further details. Can you try sharing a sample proxy here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As the error mentions you need to check your bundle before upload. The easiest way to do this is by trying to directly upload it to Apigee and see which errors you get on deployment.